# Finding the center of mass of a region between 3 curves

Tags: calculus

Let $V$ be a region in the plane consisting of all points satisfying the simultaneous conditions $|\,x\, | \leq y \leq |\, x \, | + 3$ and $y \leq 4$. Find the center of mass $(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ of $V$.

---

First, I split the region into three different regions, $V_1$,$V_2$,$V_3$, with intervals $(-4,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,4)$, respectively.

Next I found the area of each region, $A_1=\frac{9}{2}$, $A_2=6$, $A_3=\frac{9}{2}$.

Next I found the centroids of each region, using the following two formulas:

$$\overline{x}=\frac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int_a^b \left(x \cdot (f(x) - g(x))\right) \,dx $$

$$\overline{y}=\frac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int_a^b \frac{\left(f(x) - g(x)\right)\left(f(x) + g(x)\right)}{2} \,dx$$

I got $\overline{x}_1=-2$, $\overline{x}_2=0$ and $\overline{x}_3=2$, which add up to $0$.

However, $\overline{y}_1=3$, $\overline{y}_2=2$, $\overline{y}_3=3$, which adds up to $8$, and cannot be the center of $V$ since the range of $V$ is $[-4,4]$.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remember that Stack Exchange doesn't automatically latexify your posts! Putting it in LaTeX by 
wrapping it with '$' would really help us answer your question.

Comment: LaTeXified (once someone accepts my edit).

Comment: theMang, what are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This region can also be treated as a "composite object" for the purpose of locating its centroid.  As it is symmetrical about the $ \ y-$ axis, we need only find the weighted average for the $ \ y- $ coordinate of the center of mass.

[image]

Below the line $ \ y = 3 \ , $ we have a triangle of area $ \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ 3 \cdot 6 = 9 , \ $ for which the centroid is located one-third of the way from its "base" to its apex, at $ \ y = 2 \ . $  The portion above the line $ \ y = 3 \ $ consists of two parallelograms of area $ \ 1 \cdot 3 \ . $  The centroids of these parallelograms lie at $ \ y = \frac{7}{2} \ . $

The weighted average of these sectional centroids is

$$ \overline{y} \ = \ \frac{(9 \cdot 2) \ + \ 2 \ (3 \cdot \frac{7}{2})}{9 \ + \  3 \cdot 2} \ = \ \frac{18 + 21}{15} \ = \ \frac{13}{5}  , $$

with the $ \ x-$ coordinate of the overall centroid at $ \ \overline{x} = 0 \ . $

$$ \ \ $$

[image]

In your partitioning (which I've marked with green lines), it suffices to look at either the left or right half of the "chevron", since both halves will produce the same weighted average for the $ \ y-$ coordinate.  Your triangle (from |x| = 1 to |x| = 4) has area $ \ \frac{9}{2} \ $ and centroid $ \ y = 3 \ $ and your parallelogram (from x = 0 to |x| = 1) has area $ \ 3 \ $ and centroid $ \ y = 2 \ , $ so both halves have the same $ \ y-$ coordinate

$$ \overline{y} \ = \ \frac{(\frac{9}{2} \cdot 3) \ + \  \ (3 \cdot 2)}{\frac{9}{2} \ + \  3 } \ = \ \frac{\frac{27}{2} + 6}{\frac{15}{2}} \ = \ \frac{\frac{39}{2}}{\frac{15}{2}} \ = \ \frac{13}{5}  $$

as above.

As I read through your post again, in light of this second diagram, **[edit - 3/7]** your centroids for the sections are correct, but you have not "weighted" them in accordance with the areas they are associated with: you should have this second ratio I've shown, with the numerator and denominator both multiplied by 2.

Comment: +1: Wow, beautiful answer. What software did you use to create the picture?

Comment: The graph is just done with the Grapher utility on my Mac; the color-fill and a couple of details were added in Photoshop.

Comment: Very cool! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry we can see that $\bar{x} = 0$.

The total area is given by ${1\over 2} 8 \cdot 4 - {1\over 2} 2 \cdot 1 = 15$ which is what you obtained. The moment in the $y$ direction is given by
$\int_0^3 y (2y) dy +\int_3^4 y (2 \cdot 3) dy = 39$, which gives
$\bar{y} = {13 \over 5}$.